MSAL AcquireTokenInteractive redirects browser to unavaible localhost
We are using AcquireTokenInteractive to connect to EWS 365  like this:
// using Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.61.1

var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
         .CreateWithApplicationOptions(pcaOptions) // userId, tenantid
         .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
         .Build();
...

var result = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();

This is more or less what the example code does, that you can find somewhere in Entra.
We did this following this explanation:
Authentication and EWS in Exchange.
This is working fine, we get the token and everything. However the browser that was used to do the auth always does a redirect to some http://localhost:SOMEPORT that fails  and thus shows an error message.
What is it that we are doing wrong here? We did not specify any redirect uris in the portal and if we omit the WithDefaultRedirectUri() we get an error

Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: "Only loopback redirect uri is supported, but urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob was found. Configure http://localhost or http://localhost:port both during app registration and when you create the PublicClientApplication object. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-os-browser for details"

Or similar, depending if it's in the WPF app or a unit test.
Since all we care about the token (which is working), that failed browser redirect will just confuse the user. How do we get rid of it?

Could you try setting http://localhost as redirect URI in Mobile & Desktop applications platform and replace this line WithDefaultRedirectUri() with .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)?

@Sridevi didn't help. Auth works, browser fails.

What error you are getting in browser? Usually you should get this screen in browser if authentication is successful https://i.imgur.com/4vTzsdz.png

@Sridevi Default CONNECTION_RESET and then CONNECTION_REFUSED page of the browser.

Are you running it in WPF application?

@Sridevi wpf, console and unittest on .net 8.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Initially, I too got same error when I removed WithDefaultRedirectUri() line from code while getting token with interactive flow:

To resolve the error, make sure to add http://localhost as redirect URI in "Mobile and desktop applications" platform while using interactive flow for token generation:

In my case, I ran below modified code in .NET 8 console app by including redirect URI and got login screen to pick account:
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

class Program
{
    private static string _clientId = "appId";
    private static string _tenantId = "tenantId";


    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pcaOptions = new PublicClientApplicationOptions
        {
            ClientId = _clientId,
            TenantId = _tenantId
        };

        var redirectUri = "http://localhost";

        var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .CreateWithApplicationOptions(pcaOptions)
            .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
            .Build();

        var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All" };

        try
        {
            var accounts = await pca.GetAccountsAsync();
            AuthenticationResult result;

            if (accounts.Any())
            {
                result = await pca.AcquireTokenSilent(ewsScopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                    .ExecuteAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                result = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(ewsScopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Access Token:");
            Console.WriteLine(result.AccessToken);
        }
        catch (MsalException msalEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error Acquiring Token: {msalEx}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error Acquiring Token: {ex}");
        }
    }
}

Pick an account:

Once the authentication is successful, user will be redirected to this page in browser:

When I checked the output console now, I got access token successfully like this:

To confirm that, I decoded the access token in jwt.ms website where it has aud and scp claims as below:

Reference:
Default reply URI - Microsoft Authentication Library for .NET | Microsoft 

We were able to fix the Problem.
Solution:
Include current Packages:
Microsoft.Identity.Client Version="4.61.1"
Microsoft.Identity.Client.Broker Version="4.61.1"
Configure Redirect URI as "http://localhost"
Use this Code:
            private const string EXCHANGE_URL = "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx";
            private const string EXCHANGE_EWS_SCOPE = "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All";
            private const string Instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";

            var mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;

            BrokerOptions brokerOptions = new BrokerOptions(BrokerOptions.OperatingSystems.Windows);

            var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
                                                                         .WithAuthority($"{Instance}{TenantId}")
                                                                         .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
                                                                         .WithBroker(brokerOptions)
                                                                         .Build();


            // The permission scope required for EWS access
            var ewsScopes = new string[] { EXCHANGE_EWS_SCOPE };

            var op = pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(ewsScopes).WithParentActivityOrWindow(new WindowInteropHelper(mainWindow).Handle);

            // Make the interactive token request
            var authResult = op.ExecuteAsync().Result;
            SOGHotlineException.Check(!authResult.AccessToken.IsNullOrEmpty());

            AccessToken = authResult.AccessToken;

This Code needs a WindowHandle. Here retrieved from Application.Current.MainWindow. You may use your own Window.
